# Why does this task update on ClickUp show 200 as response, but the update doesn't occur using GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, clickup-api

Their documentation [example](https://clickup.com/api/clickupreference/operation/UpdateTask/) requires certain fields to be in the update body, but these `values` aren't always available. I've checked some instructions and [this](https://github.com/psolymos/clickrup/blob/master/R/api-tasks.R), for example, says that you only need to pass the one that you want to update, which is what I am doing. Keep getting 200, but the update doesn't actually happen.

```
const clickupToken = "***"
const clickupReqBody = { "Authorization": clickupToken }
const clickupUrl = "https://api.clickup.com/api/v2/"

function updateTaskStatusClickUp(updatedTaskData, taskId) {
  taskid = '476ky1';
  
  updatedTaskData = {
    "status": "COMPLETE"
  }
  
  const query = {
    custom_task_ids: 'false',
    team_id: '',
  };

  const resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    clickupUrl + `task/` + `${taskId}?${query}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: clickupToken
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(updatedTaskData)
    }
  );
  console.log(resp.getContentText());
}
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: When `body: JSON.stringify(updatedTaskData)` is modified to `payload: JSON.stringify(updatedTaskData)`, is that your expected result? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) `body` is replaced with `payload`.

Comment: Wow! At first, when I tried ```payload``` without ```JSON.stringify()```, believing that it was already in the correct format, it threw an ```Exception related error```, but when stringifying it, it DOES work! Thank you, @Tanaike!!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the `body` needs to be `payload: JSON.stringify()`, as clarified by `Google Apps Script` legend, in the question comments above.

```
const clickupToken = "***"
const clickupReqBody = { "Authorization": clickupToken }
const clickupUrl = "https://api.clickup.com/api/v2/"

function updateTaskStatusClickUp(updatedTaskData, taskId) {
  taskid = '476ky1';
  
  updatedTaskData = {
    "status": "COMPLETE"
  }
  
  const query = {
    custom_task_ids: 'false',
    team_id: '',
  };

  const resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    clickupUrl + `task/` + `${taskId}?${query}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: clickupToken
      },
      payload: JSON.stringify(updatedTaskData)
    }
  );
  console.log(resp.getContentText());
}
```